# macbook pro 2006 freezes constantly

Tags: macbook

2006 macbook pro constantly freezes, requiring hard shut down and restart. Very slow connectivity to internet and horizontal black lines across screen at random times. Running Snow Leopard on 1GB RAM. Worth saving? How to fix?

Comment: any way to check the temperature of the system?

Comment: I'll try. It's so hot that my legs are red after 10 min. if it's on my lap.

Answer (score 2):

Since its overheating, i'd try a few cheap and cheerful things - clean out the vents with compressed air, and prop up the laptop on some books. Overheating causes the EXACT same symptoms you're referring to, and it dosen't hurt to do a quick cleanup.

Answer (score 0):

**Here is what to do.**

The recommend approach is to delete your cache files. Is it safe? Yes it is. You might whant to read this before you continue. (Or perhaps use google to read more about mac cache).

Topic: MAC Is it safe to delete cache files?
(http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=874717)

---

Hi there. I am a CS student who uses my belowed mac-computer approx 5 h a day. I had the exact same problem and contacted Apple Support (phone) 3 months ago. They showed me how to solve it. So first shut the computer down (or remove the battery if it has frowzen). Then you do this.

1. Start the computer up in "safe mode". Here is how to do that. [Mac OS X: Starting up in Safe Mode](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht1455). And here is some other info which I think you can just skip. [Startup key combinations](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht1533).
   You could also (theoretically) delete cache in normal mode but. It is much better to start it in safe mode, and then delete it. The reason is that in safe mode the screen is much less likely to freeze. So start it in safe mode.
2. Open finder and delete cache files. (Cache files is temporary files used to make programs seem faster than they accutally is. If you delete them, which is perfectly safe, your mac will save new cache files. This is done everytime you start up a program for the first time and is the reason a program is slower to start the first time. New cache files is saved regularly). "" So. This is how to delete the cache files : "" (I know it souds a bit scary but it is perfectly safe, in fact it is your cache files who make your screen freeze so you have to delete them. You really don't have an option). Now I am going away from the computer but will be back in approximately 6 H if you have any questions. Just feel free to ask me and I will do my best to answer!
3. In Macintosh HD there is a folder called "Library". Open it. 
   In Library there is a folder called "Caches".
   Throw the Cache folder to your garbage can. (Move to trash). Your computer then asks for your password, type your password. Here potentially your user don't have administrator privileges. In that case. Enter username and password for a user who has administrator priviges. If this is unclear in any way, ask me.
4. Move to your "home folder" (The one which has a symbol which looks like a house). Mine has the same name as my last name. Go to the finder and click on the house-symbol in the menu to the left.
5. In your "home folder" there is a folder called "Library". Go there. Then do exactly the same thing as you did last time, I repeat: In Library there is a folder called "Caches".
   Throw the Cache folder to your garbage can. (Move to trash). Your computer then asks for your password, type your password.
6. Restart your computer. Now it should be fine and behave normally!

**Did this solve your problem?**

---

Some links. To make my point that other people recomends the same procedure. (I used google).

Topic: MacBook Pro Freezes in Login Screen
(http://discussions.info.apple.com/message.jspa?messageID=11354209)

Here user Daniel Ball writes. That you could do this. He's approach is using the command line but it is exactly the same as doing it manually. cd = change directory to. rm = remove directory. (A directory is the same thing as a folder). -rf * = do the command with super user privilages (almost the same as root user) privilges. This is what you approve of when you enter your password.
cd /System/Library/Caches
rm -rf *
cd /private/var/db/dyld
rm -rf *

Comment: I will add some links about cache soon. (I would not trust a random person so to say. But I know computers so to say and if you delete cache the computer will recreate it in seconds).

Comment: `rm` is __not__ remove directory - rmdir is remove directory.  `rm` is remove __file__.  `-rf` is __not__ super user privileges!  -r is __recursive__ and -f is __force__ - __nothing whatsoever to do with super user or privileges!__

Comment: GOOD that you pointed this out. Really, thanks! I could have looked it up in man pages (since I sometimes do perl hacking, where the man pages saves your as) but I did not think it was that important. Oh whell, I was a little lazy so to say.

Comment: COPIED FROM ABOVE MENTIONED HOMEPAGE: Running rm -rf will force deletion of everything in that directory using * :
 """""""" 
cd /Library/Caches
rm -rf *
 """""""" 
cd /System/Library/Caches
rm -rf *
 """""""" 
cd /private/var/db/dyld
rm -rf *

Comment: """""""" = makes it easier to read. at least for me.

Answer (score 0):

Well. Are you bothered that your computer gets too hot when using it?
There are products to solve this issue. Plenty of them. (I also saw a downloadable product called something with "...bee" but alas I could not find it since I didn't remember the exact name). Oh well, here you go. The product I'm thinking about is called something along the lines of laptop cooler, cooling pad etc. I actually have one myself which I bought after reading a very persuasive article in a computer-magazine. BUT I don't use it. Why? Because I get annoyed by the sound of the fan. It is not especially loud or so but still. Slightly annoying. If I where to buy a new one I'll most probably go for one made of aluminium. Since metal is good for leading of heat. 
I did some googling... Might give you some ideas. Good luck!
http://www.google.com/products/catalog?client=safari&rls=en&q=Thermapak+cooling+pad&oe=UTF-8&um=1&ie=UTF-8&cid=12119606374220816078&sa=X&ei=uUaaTZDFK8uLswaqrdnKCA&ved=0CCsQ8wIwAg#ps-sellers

http://www.google.com/products/catalog?q=Targus+cooler+pad&um=1&ie=UTF-8&cid=13531427585781362734&sa=X&ei=6EaaTffkOszssgbuifW0CA&ved=0CF8Q8wIwAQ#ps-sellers
(http://www.google.com/products/catalog?q=Targus+cooler+pad&um=1&ie=UTF-8&cid=8767060499420434462&sa=X&ei=6EaaTffkOszssgbuifW0CA&ved=0CGkQ8wIwAw#ps-sellers) I am only allowed 2 hyperlinks since I've got low points. (Upvove me and I will be a more happy man!)

*Have anyone besides me tried these kind of products?* I would be glad for imput. If you have tried a similar product; were you also bothered whith the noice? Is it just me. I sure was quite bothered with it and to be frank. I did not think the product were worth its money.

Comment: If you feel hacky you could explore methods for controlling your fan. The fan is controlled by software and that software can be manipulated in different ways. I guess that you can find scripts for doing this. (Of course always make a backup before you try this).

Answer (score 0):

The lines on the screen indicate hardware problems, but you really need to narrow this down before you can determine this to be the case.

First thing, create a new user account and see if the freezing still takes place while using the new account. Other things you can do are boot from fresh install, or if you have a friend with a Mac, boot their computer into target mode (hold down 't' when booting) and then boot of that hard drive. This will narrow down if it's software or hardware related.

Honestly, with an old Mac like that, if it is hardware it's probably not worth it to get it fixed, but try the above first.

Answer (score 0):

An additional option if the problem is overheating: Google "smcFanControl" and you should find a piece of software intended to let you control your internal fan speed.  Up it if it's not already at the maximum and that should help.

If the issues persist when you take care of the heat problem, it may be due to a logic board soldering defect.  Certain MBP models circa your timeframe had an issue with this but it generally showed up in display problems and *not* in network connectivity, as far as I know.  Either way, if you're in the US and running your original hardware, Apple will fix it for $310+tax - or if you feel adventurous and the machine isn't worth the $310 to you, you can try baking the board yourself.